# Add CSS Arrow to Top Left of Div

Tags: html, css

I have tried to tweak the CSS from 
http://jsfiddle.net/wn7JN/ to place an arrow in a `<div>` in the top left corner (see image below), but I can't seem to figure out how `:before` and `:after` in CSS work. Every time I update the `bottom` and `left` parameters I am left with a black arrow in the top left corner - I think the proper rotation is `transform: rotate(220deg)` but that is really a guess.

Edit: Is it possible to do this same CSS trick with an `rgba` color such as `rgba(255, 123, 172, 0.25)`? When I test it out the transparency becomes an issue with the border overlap.

[image: <div> with Arrow]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 175px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 25px 0;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 174px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 26px 26px 0;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"> </div>
```

Comment: Post the code you've already tried here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this. Added a working copy.

```css
.bubble {
position: relative;
background:#cbe8f0;
height: 100px;
width:170px;
margin-left:30px;
border-radius:2px;
}

.bubble:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border:10px solid transparent;
  border-top:10px solid #cbe8f0;
  top:0px;
  left:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"> </div>
```

Comment: Wow that is easy...for you!

Comment: so I ran into a small problem. The color I need to use happens to be `rgba(13, 157, 196, 0.25)` which happens to break this snippet, i.e. the colors don't overlap correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: is it compulsory to use opacity in `rgba`? 
If no then use the `hex` code without opacity.

Note: `0.25` is for opacity.

Answer (score 1):

You can ty this solution too based on the jsfiddle.

```
.bubble:after 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left: -21px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 24px 0px 0px 28px;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top:-1px;
left:-23px;
border-style: solid;
border-width:20px 0px 0px 23px;
border-color: #000 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wn7JN/1295/

Answer (score 0):

So, here's your bubble code:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Add this line to the bottom of that: `margin-left:25px;` This allows there to be room to the side of your bubble for the arrow to even show up. Otherwise, it's there, but you can't see it.

for your `bubble:after`, change the `bottom: -25px` to `top: 21px` and change `left: 175px` to `left: -37px`, and add `transform: rotate(90deg);` to the bottom.

for your `bubble:before`, change the `top: 250px` to `top: 20px` and change `left: 174px` to `left: -39px`, and add `transform: rotate(90deg);` to the bottom.

You will wind up with something like this:

[image: bubble with arrow in top left][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2cMv.png)

Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eq6mhbwy/